# How to create browseable class-properties in .NET / Visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-interface, components

How I can make something like this in VS properties Window (collapsible multi properties):

[image]

I tried such code:

```
   Test z = new Test();

    [ Browsable(true)]
    public Test _TEST_ {
        get { return z; }
        set { z = value; }
    }
```

Where "Test" class is:

```
[Browsable(true)] 
public class Test {
    [Browsable(true)] 
    public string A { get;set; }
    [Browsable(true)] 
    public string B { get;set; }
}
```

But this gives me only grayed-out name of class

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` or/and `DebuggerBrowsableAttribute` instead? [Enhancing Debugging with the Debugger Display Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes)

Comment: Nevermind first comment. I t is more about debugging windows not properties window. Maybe this will be better link for you to figure out how to do it. [Extend properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/extending-properties?view=vs-2019)

Comment: As you noticed - this is not I was asking for. I think I might need here definition kind of editor helping properties window

Comment: Still haven't figured it out, but I think this is important:
    `[TypeConverter(typeof(SizeConverter))]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I got something to work that may satisfy your case.

To get a class to expand in the PropertyGrid, you have to add a `TypeConverterAttribute` to it, referencing the type of an `ExpandableObjectConverter` (or something else that derives from it).

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Test
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

---

The only problem is that it now displays the type name (the return value of its `ToString()` method as the value of your class). You can either live with it (which you probably won't want to), change the `ToString()` return value to something more fitting or use a custom `TypeConverter` for that case.

I'll show you a quick implementation on how the latter could be done:

```
internal class TestConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return "";
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

And then you would write this, instead of what I wrote above:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TestConverter))]
public class Test
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

This just empties the information and prevents the user to enter some other value. You probably want to show something more descriptive which is completely up to you.
It is also possible to get information and parse it into useful values. A good example would be the location, which is an object of type `Point` visualized with `[10,5]` when `X` is `10` and `Y` is `5`. When you enter new values they are parsed and set to the integers that are referenced by the original string.

---

Because I couldn't find much about the topic, I looked up some references in [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), because it had to be done before. In my case, I peeked into [ButtonBase](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonBase.cs) and [FlatButtonAppearance](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FlatButtonAppearance.cs) of WindowsForms to see how Microsoft did it, back in the day.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the TypeConverter Class.  This allows VS properties to access your object as strings, and convert back to it from strings.

for more about [TypeConversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ayybcxe5(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

```
class MultiPropConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string)) { return true; }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture,
        object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string[] v = ((string)value).Split(new char[] { ',' });
            if(v.Length == 3) // Check that there are no ',' in your string(s) A.
            {
                return new DropDownProperties(v[0], float.Parse(v[1]), int.Parse(v[2]));
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture,
        object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string)) // What VS properties ask for to display
        {
            DropDownProperties dDP = (DropDownProperties)value;
            return dDP.A + "," + dDP.B.ToString() + "," + dDP.C.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

the Multi-Property Class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MultiPropConverter))]
public class DropDownProperties
{       
    [Description("Description of A")]
    public string A { get; set; } = "Default";      
    [Description("Description of B")]
    public float B { get; set; } = 0f;
    [Description("Description of C")]
    public int C { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

And then class instantiation:

```
    [Description("Category Description"), Category("ACategory")]
    public DropDownProperties dropProp { get; set; } = new DropDownProperties() 
    { A = "Hello World", B = "0.1", C = 0};
```

You do not need the Browsable attribute if you include a category or description for the item.

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already good answers by others.

Browseable(true/false) means it can be browsed in the property window. 
Please note, the Visual Studio properties editor will only show public properties. Private properties are hidden and can't be browsed for various reasons.

Public properties are browsable by default. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=netcore-3.1

The designer will always only show one value per default for strings, multi-property dropdowns only work for integers afaik.

Also, there is EditorBrowsable which defines whether or not Intellisense shows your property.

You can do something like this:

```
public class Column
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsablestate?view=netcore-3.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The question has the properties as public, and that is incorrect that multi-property dropdowns only work for integers as I have clearly displayed in my answer.

Comment: should have added "per default"